# ExcelScript (Online): Get current file name

Tags: excel, office-scripts

I'm trying to automate with Office-Scripts and Microsoft Power Automate (former Flow) some process.
I simply try to get the current file name of each excel file, but I am failing the whole time.

How do I get the current filename?
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {

```
  console.log(ExcelScript.Workbook.getName());
    
}
```

The documetion is not clear to me at this point -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office-scripts/excelscript/excelscript.workbook?view=office-scripts

Answer (score 1):

Got it. The solution is console.log(Workbook.getName()); – Paintitblack3k just now